# SVN: how to make sure I synced the trunk to a branch correctly

Tags: svn, svn-merge

I am using SVN and creating branches for each "meety" feature that I am adding to our website.

On a regular basis, I sync the trunk to my branch using this command (from my branch's working directory):

```
svn merge ^/trunk
```

I was wondering if, straight after that operation, I can run any command to make sure the merge operation was successful.

I heard I can use the command `svn propget svn:mergeinfo` but I can't understand how.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[mergeinfo](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html) just tells you what revisions have been merged into your branch, that's all. You can get the same info just by looking at the output of your merge command, it won't really tell you any more than that.

I'm not sure what else you want, the merge commend will tell you what revisions and files were merged in.

Addendum:

SVN 1.8 was released, I've just checked [the release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#merge-tracking-enhancements) and there is this bit of info:

> In Subversion 1.8, the -r option restricts the output of svn mergeinfo
>   to the specified revision range, which is useful when determining
>   whether or not a given revision, or range of revisions, is eligible
>   for merging, or whether it has already been merged. In the following
>   example, r682012 has not been merged from trunk yet, while r26112011
>   has already been merged:
>
> ```
> $ svn mergeinfo --show-revs=eligible -r 682012 ^/trunk
> r682012
> $ svn mergeinfo --show-revs=merged -r 26112011 ^/trunk
> r26112011
> ```

Comment: How should I launch the mergeinfo command? Is there anything in its output that will hint something went wrong?